# Swift Multiple Text Field Arguments

Tags: ios, swift, textfield

I have multiple restrictions I would like to add to 2 seperate textFields.

textField1
, textField2

**Both Text Fields**

- Only Allow One Decimal
- Only allow 8 characters in length

"shouldChangeCharactersIn" - How can I use this function to apply to multiple textFields and have multiple constraints?

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField,shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange,replacementString string: String) -> Bool
    {
    let countdots = (capitalInvested.text?.components(separatedBy: ".").count)! - 1

        if countdots > 0 && string == "."
        {
            return false
        }
        return true
        }
```

Comment: check inside `shouldChangeCharactersIn` `if (textField  == textField1 || textField2)  { // apply your both conditions}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check which text field is being typed in, which calls the function:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if textField == textField1 {
        // first text field
        // add restrictions here
    } else if textField == textField2 {
        // second text field
        // add restrictions here
    }
    if textField == textField1 || textField == textField2 {
        // restrictions for both
    }
}
```